# Why gcc in 64 bit ubuntu doesn't detect the following array overflow?

Tags: c++, gcc

So my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char *a="123456789abcdef";
    char b[10];
    int i=0;
    while((b[i]=a[i])!='\0')
        ++i;
    printf("%s, %d\n",b,strlen(b));
    return 0;
}
```

The code exists a array overflow with array b, but when I compile it with gcc(version 4.6.3) in my system (64bit ubuntu 12.04 lts),it succeed. 
The output of this program is **123456789abcdef, 15** and 
returns 0 means this program exits normally.
 I don't know whether it's my compiler's problem or my system's, is there anyone can tell me?
P.S. It seems like it only appears in 64-bit linux with gcc. Is this a bug?

Comment: Compiling with Clang returns `123456789ab@, 13`.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct your code. 1: main must be int. 2: a must be const. 3: printf had a missing ). btw, I get a segfault.

Comment: thank you,btw for c,function is set to int in default.It should get a segfault,so what complier and system do you use!

Answer (score 7):

Array accesses are not checked in C. If you overflow a buffer like this, the result is undefined behavior. It is the programmer's responsibility to guard against this, not the compiler's.

There are tools though to assist in checking for invalid memory access. Like Valgrind for doing so at runtime, and Clang's static analyzer for compile-time checking.

Comment: first,thank you!I know it's programmer's responsibility to guard against buffer overflow,I'm just curious of whether this is a bug.I ask my friend to run this in his 64-bit system,the result

Comment: the result is the same,when run it in 32-bit system,it will not succeed,so can we say it caused by the compatibility of gcc and 64-bit linux?

Comment: @CocooWang It is a bug in your code :-) When you write to memory that you shouldn't, you get undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything can happen. The program might crash, or it might not. That's what "undefined" means.